# How to test directory for todays log that ends in .1106 for today

Tags: unix

I'm new at this. I need to write a unix script to check a directory for todays log which will end in .1106 or .todays date in month and day, and then grep the log for ERROR. I don't want to change the date and time on the server or anything, I just need to pick out todays log and check it. What's the best way I can check a directory for a file that ends in todays date thats just month and day. The logs all look like: current_log.1106 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +%m%d`
echo "Files matching *.$DATE and containing ERROR: "
grep -l "ERROR" *.$DATE
```

?